# Calling an Ember _super method from Promise handler

Tags: ember.js, coffeescript, promise, rsvp.js

I'm trying to make use of _super in the handler of a Promise inside of a Controller action, but it doesn't work because it seems to lose the correct chain of functions.

```
ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend SimpleAuth.ApplicationRouteMixin,
  actions:
    sessionAuthenticationSucceeded: ->
      @get("session.user").then (user) =>
        if @get("session.isTemporaryPassword") or not user.get "lastLogin"
          @transitionTo "temp-password"
        else
          @_super()
```

I want to revert to the Mixin's default behavior on the `else` but I need to resolve `user` asynchronously before I can do a conditional statement. I tried:

```
ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend SimpleAuth.ApplicationRouteMixin,
  actions:
    sessionAuthenticationSucceeded: ->
      _super = @_super
      @get("session.user").then (user) =>
        if @get("session.isTemporaryPassword") or not user.get "lastLogin"
          @transitionTo "temp-password"
        else
          _super()
```

and

```
ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend SimpleAuth.ApplicationRouteMixin,
  actions:
    sessionAuthenticationSucceeded: ->
      @get("session.user").then (user) =>
        if @get("session.isTemporaryPassword") or not user.get "lastLogin"
          @transitionTo "temp-password"
        else
          @_super.bind(@)()
```

Neither works.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24144471/ember-js-this-super-in-a-callback-function) claimed this should work as of 1.5.0, but I'm using 1.7.0-beta.5 and it's no go. Is there a way to get this to work, even in terms of approaching this differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ember currently doesn't support calling `_super` asynchronously.  In that example I'm not actually calling `_super` asynchronously, it's synchronous still.

http://emberjs.com/blog/2014/03/30/ember-1-5-0-and-ember-1-6-beta-released.html#toc_ever-present-_super-breaking-bugfix

Answer (score 0):

In order to continue the bubbling you need to call `this.target.send()` with the name of the action.

see: [How can I bubble up an Ember action inside a callback function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25189288/how-can-i-bubble-up-an-ember-action-inside-a-jquery-callback-function/25195073#25195073)

Something like this should work:

```
ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend SimpleAuth.ApplicationRouteMixin,
  actions:
    sessionAuthenticationSucceeded: ->
      @get("session.user").then (user) =>
        if @get("session.isTemporaryPassword") or not user.get "lastLogin"
          @transitionTo "temp-password"
        else
          @target.send('sessionAuthenticationSucceeded')
```

Comment: Hmm, will that work for what I want to accomplish? I want to have the default behavior (found in the Mixin code) run on an `else`, not to bubble the action to a different class in the chain.